# Do I need to run a function for LightBox2 plugin?

Tags: javascript, lightbox, lightbox2

I am using the LightBox2 plugin by Lokesh Dhakar. http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

I don't see anything in the documentation for running the function. I apologize if this is an obvious answer, I am new to plugins and have not encountered this. The plugin is not working after following all posted steps. I can post my code at a later time, however my question as of now is interpreting the documentation for the plugin.

Edit: Thank you so much for confirming! What is strange is that there are no errors in my console and my HTML code is valid. However when I click on an image, it is still redirecting to load in another page and not running the lightbox at all.

[Code Page 1][1], 
[Code Page 2][2]

Thanks!

Comment: In the documentation, i don't see anything about a "startup function". This should work without anything. Do you have any error in the javascript console ? You should post your code, perhaps you have missed something

Comment: There is no need to call any function to start the Lightbox. You can initialize the lightbox right in your HTML. Include the script tag and the css in the HTML file and the on one of the images like this `<a href="images/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption">Image #1</a>`

It should work out of the box! If it doesn't let us know the errors you are seeing and we can help!